# How can I create a pattern from SMS text string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a sample sms "Spent Rs 300.00 at Shop Name from card number XXXX2123". It's like assume any bank sms you receive in mobile after your transaction.

I need to write a robust program in python.

I came up with the following solution thinking about only given string.

```
def split_string(samplestring):
    list_string = samplestring.split(' ')
    return list_string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    samplestring = 'Spent Rs 300.00 at Shop Name from card number XXXX2123'

    list_string = split_string(samplestring)
    #print(list_string)

    print("Spent/Added:" + list_string[0])
    #print(list_string[0])

    print("Amount Type:"+ list_string[1])
    #print(list_string[1])

    print("Amount:"+ list_string[2])
    #print(list_string[2])

    print("Location where used:" + list_string[4] + list_string[5])
    #print(list_string[4] + list_string[5])

    print("Card Number:" + list_string[9])
    #print(list_string[9])
```

Output should be like:

```
Spent/Added:Spent
Amount Type:Rs
Amount:300.00
Location where used:ShopName
Card Number:XXXX2123
```

But this won't work in following case :
1. this won't work if the name of shop is single workd or if there is any extra character in the message
2. also it won't work with different type of SMSs from different bank

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why don't you store the values in a dictionary and then format them into your string?

Comment: Where does `samplestring` come from in the actual application? I'm trying to work out whether this is a regex type problem or whether your initial design is off.

Comment: @roganjosh The samplestring is your bank sms ! Any sms your receive after transaction using your bank account. It can be ICICI, SBI or anything.

Comment: Why did you attempt to remove almost all the text in my answer by editing it?  See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21123576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for the sample SMS:

```
import re
def split_str(s):
    print('Spent/Added:',re.sub('.*(Spent|Added).*', '\\1', s))
    print('Amount Type:', re.sub('.*?\s+?([a-zA-Z\W]+)\s+?[0-9]+.*', '\\1', s))
    print('Amount:',re.sub('.*?[A-Za-z\W]+(.*?)\sat.*', '\\1', s))
    print('Location where used:',re.sub('.*?at\s+(.*?)\s+from.*', '\\1', s))
    print('Card Number:',re.sub('.*?((X{4})([0-9]{4})).*?', '\\1', s))
    print('Full Card Number:',re.sub('.*?(([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{4})).*?', '\\1', s))
```

**Example 1:**

```
s = 'Spent Rs 300.00 at Shop Name from card number XXXX2123'
split_str(s)
```

result:

```
Spent/Added: Spent
Amount Type: Rs
Amount: 300.00
Location where used: Shop Name
Card Number: XXXX2123
Full Card Number: Spent Rs 300.00 at Shop Name from card number XXXX2123
```

**Example 2:**

```
s = 'Spent $ 3 000 000 000.78 at Bgees & Inc. from card number 1111 2222 3333 4444'
split_str(s)
```

result:

```
Spent/Added: Spent
Amount Type: $
Amount: 3 000 000 000.78
Location where used: Bgees & Inc.
Card Number: Spent $ 3 000 000 000.78 at Bgees & Inc. from card number 1111 2222 3333 4444
Full Card Number: 1111 2222 3333 4444
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse machine-generated short text messages into specific values.

What you might try is to create a list of regular expressions which you build up over time as you discover new message formats.  When you receive a message, try to parse it using each regular expression until one matches.  If none matches, create an alert to be reviewed later so new regular expressions can be created.

You could also build a mapping of source phone numbers to expected regular expressions, but this may only be an optimization, since there may be new phone numbers you haven't seen before from the same banks.

A regular expression for your sample `'Spent Rs 300.00 at Shop Name from card number XXXX2123'` might be:

```
r'Spent Rs (\d+)\.(\d\d) at (.*) from card number (\d+)'
```